# Write a trigger on Quote object to populate that "Sales Tax" (Lookup) according to: Bill to State/Province Bill to City

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, before-trigger, after-trigger

Experts,

I had been working on this issue for quite a few days but with no luck and need your help.

1.) Create a new object Sales Tax:

Fields:

City: Text

State: Text

Sales Tax %: Percentage

2.) Create a lookup field "Sales Tax"(Lookup) in Quote Object.

3.) Write a trigger on Quote object to populate that "Sales Tax" (Lookup) according to:

```
Bill to State/Province
```

Bill to City

Fields of quote that are matching with Sales Tax custom object record.

I am new to Triggers, but here is my piece of code where I need help:

My Code IS:-----///

```
trigger citymatchwithsalestax on Quote(before insert,before update) {
    Map<String,Quote[]> assotiactedsalestax = new Map<String,Quote[]>();
        for(Quote asssales : trigger.New){
          if(!assotiactedsalestax.containsKey(asssales .BillingAddress)){
            assotiactedsalestax.put(asssales .BillingAddress, new Quote[]{});
                        }

          assotiactedsalestax.get(asssales .BillingAddress).add(asssales );
          }
          for(Sales_Tax__c a : [select Id,State__c, Name from Sales_Tax__c where 
                  [![enter image description here][1]][1]State__c in : assotiactedsalestax.keySet()]){
            for(Quote asssales : assotiactedsalestax.get(a.State__c)){
               asssales.Sales_Tax__c = a.Id;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  trigger QuoteTrigger on Quote (before insert) {
    Map<String ,Id> salMap = new Map<String ,Id>();
    FOR(Sales_Tax__c SAL : [select Id,City__c,State__c from Sales_Tax__c]) {
       salMap.put(SAL.City__c+ '-' +SAL.State__c, SAL.Id);
    }
    for(Quote quo :trigger.new) {
        system.debug(quo.BillingCity);
        if((quo.BillingCity != null ||quo.BillingCity != '') && (quo.BillingState != null || quo.BillingState !='')) {
            if(salMap.containsKey(quo.BillingCity+ '-' +quo.BillingState))
            quo.Sales_Tax__c = salMap.get(quo.BillingCity+ '-' +quo.BillingState);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger SalesTaxPopulatingOnQuotes on Quote (before insert, before update) {
    for(Quote q : Trigger.New){
        for(SalesTax__c salesObj : [select id, city__c, State__c from SalesTax__c]){
            if(salesObj.City__c == q.BillingCity && salesObj.State__c == q.BillingState){                
                q.Sales_Tax__c = salesObj.id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include comments on why the code you suggest is a good solution rather than just posting it without explanation. See [answer]

Answer (score 0):

**Bulkified Version**

```
public void populatingSalesTaxOnQuotes(List quoteList){   
        Map SalesTaxMap = new Map();
        for(SalesTax__c SalesObj : [select id, city__c, State__c from SalesTax__c]){
            SalesTaxMap.put(SalesObj.city__c + ',' + SalesObj.State__c, SalesObj.id);
        }
        String address;        
        for(Quote q : quoteList){
            address=q.BillingCity+','+q.BillingState;
            if(SalesTaxMap.containsKey(address)){
                q.Sales_Tax__c = SalesTaxMap.get(address);                
            }
        }
}
```